# After running subprocess.Popen or os.system or hardcoding the pi to take a picture, the code exits

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system, meta-raspberrypi

Currently I am writing a script that will take a picture with a picam on my raspberry pi. But when I run my code it exits after I call the camera to take a picture. I have tried using

```
subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'raspistill', '-w', '320', '-h', '240', '-hf', '-o',  '/home/pi/Documents/Python/robot1/image0.jpg'])
```

as well as

```
os.system('sudo raspistill -w 320 -h 240 -o /home/pi/Documents/Python/robot1/image0.jpg')
```

and

```
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(2)
camera.capture('/home/pi/Documents/Python/robot1/image01.jpg')
camera.stop_preview()
```

but whenever either of these lines are run, my script exits. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: can you try without "sudo" ?

Comment: @ErikCederstrand there is no error message, when I run the code in the terminal, the script just exits.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no, because I am keyboard input to tell the camera to take a picture, I need to use sudo.

Comment: What's the return value of `os.system()`? Or stdout and stderr from the `Popen` call? What happens if you run the command directly from a terminal? Also, I assume the script writes the picture you have taken to `/home/pi/Documents/Python/robot1/image01.jpg`. Does that exist after the script exits?

Comment: you could use `sudo` to run your python script instead.